# Recurring payments system in javacript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multithreading, ethereum, setinterval

I want to build a recurring payments sytem that allows users to create payments that will be paid on interval (daily, weekly, monthly). The transactions will actually be in ether, you don't need any knowledge about blockchain development to help in this question, I just want to give a little background to explain my situation. I wrote a smart contract that handles the creation of the payment and trasfer of the token. I have a Pay() function that I would like to call from the javascript side for every interval. Essentially, this is a system that will handle many users and each user has multiple payments that he/she created. I need to build a function in javascript that will automatically call the Pay() function in the contract for each interval, for each payment that exists to that interval continuously in the background. Like a banking system's standing order. Does anyone know how to do that?

I thought using setInterval will help, but I need to use it for every interval I have (daily, weekly, monthly), and javascript is single-threaded and I didn't know how to bypass that. I thought Async wouldn't work because I don't want to wait for the call to happen, I want to handle multiple users simultanously. I'm a bit lost, and not so much experienced with javascript. Would appreciate someone's help.

Comment: If you want the payments to happen periodically, wouldn't it be a better idea to do that on the side of the contract instead of the client side. Because what if the payments has to happen daily but the user doesn't open the browser for a week, then no client side code will be executed.

Comment: The problem is, you can't call a function inside the contract. a contract is just a set of variables, structs and functions that can only be called from outside it or inside other functions. Is there a way to have the payment system running constantly, perhaps building a server or using the cloud?

Comment: Hmm this seems to be more complicated to do then it sounds.

Comment: Maybe users could approve their funds to be used by your contract. Then you would have an server where users would subscribe to some payment interval, and the server would periodically trigger a transaction to your contract on specific interval for every user that is subscribed to that interval. Don't know if this is possible actually and it seems like a non decentralized way of doing it.

Comment: Yes this is not a very centralized way but that's exactly what I was going for. I had to compromise on a hybrid approach but the function Pay() which the server calls to has requirements and security measures that make it decentralized and trustless enough. Plus, I plan to make a button that by entering payment id and clickling it, the user can by himself execute the function if the payment is not up tp date. It is a work around but it is enough for what I'm trying to do. The problem is, I don't have enough knowledge in programming to achieve this (building the server).

Comment: I have the function Pay() in the contract that already handles the transfer of money, I just don't know how to call it from the server.

Comment: Pay() delievers X amount of ether to recipient until its no longer due. I just need to call it from the server daily/monthly.

Comment: I think you could just use the same libraries that you would use on the client side to trigger a transaction which is etherjs or web3.

Comment: This probably has more to do with scheduled worker queues like celery.